# Are there any entire two-to-one function from $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an entire function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ such that for every $b \in \Bbb{C}$, the equation $f(z) = b$ has exactly two distinct roots in $\Bbb{C}$?

Answer (score 7):

By Picard's theorem, any such function must have a pole at $\infty$, therefore it must be a polynomial. Now, it is clear that any such polynomial must be of degree $2$. However, $az^2+bz+c=h$ has exactly one solution for $h=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't follow most of your steps. Which Picard theorem are you talking about? And why does having a pole at infinity imply it must be a polynomial?

Comment: It's Picard's Great Theorem, in the strong form that in a neighbourhood of an essential singularity, the function takes (with at most one exception) each complex value infinitely many times. @PerryAinsworth

Answer (score 2):

Such a function would give a double covering of $\Bbb C$. But $\Bbb C$ is simply connected: it has no connected space covering it doubly.

Comment: This seems plausible but I'm not totally convinced that such an $f$ is necessarily a covering map without a bit more work. You can construct very silly examples of maps $f : X \to Y$ such that every preimage has exactly two points but $f$ isn't a covering map, for example you can take $Y = [0, 1]$ and $X = S^1 \sqcup \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't need the full strength of Picard or any topological considerations, but standard complex analysis is enough using the following 3 facts:

1: If $f$ entire and there are $\delta, R >0$ s.t. $|f(z)| \ge \delta$ for $|z| \ge R$, then $f$ is a polynomial (consider $\frac{1}{f(\frac{1}{z})}$, show that zero is a removable singularity, conclude $f$ grows like a polynomial at infinity, use Liouville)

2: If $f$ is entire and at most $k$ to $1$ with $k \ge 1$ finite, minimal (so exists $a$ s.t $f(z)=a$ has exactly $k$ solutions), then by taking $f-a$ one can assume wlog $f$ has exactly $k$ zeros and then an easy application of the open mapping theorem shows that for some $\delta >0$, all the values in the disc of center $0$ and radius $\delta$ are taken only near the solutions of $f(z)=0$ hence $f$ satisfies 1 above, hence it's a polynomial (of degree $k$ perforce)

3: If $k \ge 2$ (as in our problem where $k=2$), $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1 \ge 1$, so it has roots, hence $f$ has critical points and values and at such, it cannot be $k$ to $1$